# Use arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion() on a list

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, feature-class, error-000732, jupyter-notebook

This works on a single feature class:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

'''
convert feature class to shapefile in Data folder
'''

arcpy.env.workspace = r'\\uncpathto\J\Python\Data'
in_feature = r'\\uncpathto\J\Python\Data\gissql01.sde\gisedit.DBO.Tax_Elem_School_Dist'

#arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(in_features, out_path, out_name)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_feature, arcpy.env.workspace, 'Tax_Elem_School_Dist')
```

**Goal:** However, what I want to do is convert a list of feature classes to shapefiles in a folder. The feature classes are all housed in an Enterprise Geodatabase.

**What I've done** is create two lists that I want to iterate and then call from the `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass()` function. The `sdeFiles` list is meant to be the names of the `in_features` parameter and the `out` list has the names of the `out_name` parameter. This is a stand-alone script.

```py
'''
Save every file in the list to a shapefile in Data folder
'''
arcpy.env.workspace = r'\\uncpathto\J\Python\Data'

sdeFiles = ['gisedit.DBO.Tax_Elem_School_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Comm_College_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_High_School_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Unit_School_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Library_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Park_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Fire_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_TIF_Dist']

out = ['Tax_Elem_School_Dist', 'Tax_Comm_College_Dist', 'Tax_High_School_Dist', 
       'Tax_Unit_School_Dist', 'Tax_Library_Dist', 'Tax_Park_Dist', 'Tax_Fire_Dist',
       'Tax_TIF_Dist']
```

- 1st attempt: use a counter on the `out` list. It yields no error. However, the only thing in the folder is Tax_Elem_School_Dist.shp.

```py
path_to_sde_connectionfile = r'\\uncpathto\J\Python\Data\gissql01.sde'
c = 0
for n in sdeFiles:
    #join sde connection file path with name of feature class to use as in_feature parameter
    newname = os.path.join(path_to_sde_connectionfile, n)
    
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(newname, arcpy.env.workspace, out[c])
c+=1
```

- 2nd attempt: iterate lists in two `for` loops. Yields `ERROR 000732`.

```py
path_to_sde_connectionfile = r'\\uncpathto\J\Python\Data\gissql01.sde'
for s in sdeFiles:
    inFeature = os.path.join(path_to_sde_connectionfile, s)
    for o in out:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(s, arcpy.env.workspace, o)

#yields error: 
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset gisedit.DBO.Tax_Elem_School_Dist does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert all feature classes in a geodatabase to  shp or only a subset represented by the list? Either way, I would split the sde name by "." and grab the last string rather than pulling a string from a name list. Then include that in the "name" parameter.

Comment: Deleting and reposting closed questions can spur SE anti-spam defenses to block your account. All you really need is to `zip` the two lists together, so you have a `src,tgt` pair. Best practice would include using `os.path.join` to prepend the connection file to the source and to append a `.shp` suffix to the `tgt` prefix. (at which point you won't need to mention the workspace).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I provided a comprehensive answer to this question (with slightly different code) yesterday, and that question (and answer) has now disappeared.  I can't be bothered doing it again.

Comment: Indeed you did. And thank you. I made a bunch of changes and thought it was best to start over, so I deleted it. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should automatically list the files you need using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` in order to avoid errors. However, if you have to select specific FC's, here is an approach that extracts the output name from the SDE FC name using [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) rather than using two lists:

```
import arcpy

path_to_sde_connectionfile = '/uncpathto/J/Python/Data/gissql01.sde'
out_folder = '/path/to/your/outfolder'


sdeFiles = ['gisedit.DBO.Tax_Elem_School_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Comm_College_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_High_School_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Unit_School_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Library_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Park_Dist', 
            'gisedit.DBO.Tax_Fire_Dist', 'gisedit.DBO.Tax_TIF_Dist']

for sdeFile in sdeFiles:
    # Join sde connection file path with name of SDE FC
    in_features = os.path.join(path_to_sde_connectionfile, sdeFile)
    out_name = sdeFile.split('.')[2]
    
    # Convert SDE FC to shp
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features, out_folder, out_name)
```

Comment: The ```.split()``` was handy. The code works nicely as well. Also, the code that I had with the counter is also working. ```c+=1``` needed to be indented.